# <iterator object azure.core.paging.ItemPaged at 0x1e56b175840> How to Iterate this type of object

Tags: python, azure, azure-application-insights, azure-python-sdk

Package Name: azure-mgmt-applicationinsights
Package Version: 4.0.0
Operating System: Windows
Python Version: 3.11.2
Describe the bug
A clear and concise description of what the bug is.

I am using Python azure-mgmt-applicationinsights SDK to work around Application Insights, I have found that i cannot able to iterate <iterator object azure.core.paging.ItemPaged at 0x1e56b175840> object response from below code

```
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.mgmt.applicationinsights.v2015_05_01 import ApplicationInsightsManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.applicationinsights.v2015_05_01.operations import WebTestsOperations

credential = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id="4499593dmkfnskxsgcstec",
client_id="44955945949493932eeew",
client_secret="xxxxxxffddddeedd")

client = ApplicationInsightsManagementClient(credential=credential,
subscription_id="5cd41c92-754a-486e-95ff-f1fc311c0fa2")

client = ApplicationInsightsManagementClient(credential=credential,
subscription_id="5cd41c92-754a-486e-95ff-f1fc311c0fa2")

response = client.web_tests.get(
resource_group_name="-QA-RG",
web_test_name="response-test-service-availability",
)
print(response)

web_test_configuration_hard_coded = ""`your text`"

"""
operation = WebTestsOperations(client="https://management.azure.com", config=web_test_configuration_hard_coded, serializer=True, deserializer=True)
paged_object = operation.list()

print(paged_object)

for pages in paged_object:
print(pages)
```

**Error output:**

```
<class 'azure.core.paging.ItemPaged'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\VinayT\PycharmProjects\Azure-Python\application_insights.py", line 68, in
for r in paged_object:
File "C:\Users\VinayT\PycharmProjects\Azure-Python\venv\lib\site-packages\azure\core\paging.py", line 132, in next
return next(self._page_iterator)
File "C:\Users\VinayT\PycharmProjects\Azure-Python\venv\lib\site-packages\azure\core\paging.py", line 76, in next
self._response = self._get_next(self.continuation_token)
File "C:\Users\VinayT\PycharmProjects\Azure-Python\venv\lib\site-packages\azure\mgmt\applicationinsights\v2015_05_01\operations_web_tests_operations.py", line 833, in get_next
request = prepare_request(next_link)
File "C:\Users\VinayT\PycharmProjects\Azure-Python\venv\lib\site-packages\azure\mgmt\applicationinsights\v2015_05_01\operations_web_tests_operations.py", line 798, in prepare_request
subscription_id=self._config.subscription_id,
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'subscription_id'
```

also help we with the right parameters to pass for config and client

Need to Iterate from the respose object  of type PagedItem

Can I able to fetch Response Body from Failed request using Rest API or SDK for below requests

[Application insights Failed Requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLWdV.png)

Comment: `client_secret=xxxxxxffddddeedd"` is mising an opening quote, which messes up the rest of the code. You should first solve that, since your code is otherwise not runnable

Comment: it is not related to quotes. Thanks

Comment: now you have a line `web_test_configuration_hard_coded = ""`your text`"` with only one closing quote. The next line has three quotes, effectively closing the previous line and adding an empty string that does nothing.  The last line of your code is missing indentation and will cause an error

Comment: @VINAYTALLA adding to point we can also configurator  
Sembei Norimaki```web_test_configuration_hard_coded = {
    # Define your configuration here
}```

Comment: @VINAY TALLA Make sure that the for loops are indented with four spaces (or a tab) under the corresponding `for` statements. This should resolve the indentation error you're encountering.

Comment: @VINAYTALLA the `for` loop get the List all web tests in a resource group

Comment: @VINAYTALLA  added the Application Insights availability tests from the [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/availability-overview) and [MSDOC2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/availability-standard-tests)

Comment: @VINAYTALLA The error is due to incorrect usage of the `WebTestsOperations` class. Instead of directly instantiating the` WebTestsOperation` class, We can use the `client.web_tests` attribute.  which is already an instance of WebTestsOperations.using the `paged_object` we receive from the `list_by_resource_group` method.

Comment: I will give a sample code snippet the way to iterate over the paged response using the `paged_object` So we receive from the `list_by_resource_group `method.

Comment: please give like this i.e :`web_test_name = "sampath-sampath23333"` for  `"testname-ApplicationInsightsName"`

Comment: @VINAYTALLA used `for page in paged_object.by_page():` is used to iterate through the pages of results returned by the `list_by_resource_group` operation for web tests. The `by_page()` method is a generator that returns each page of results one by one. Inside the loop for `page in paged_object.by_page():` .`for web_test in page:` iterating through each web test within the current page. The variable `web_test` represents each individual web test object within the current page of results.

Comment: @Sampath  Hi Sampath, I am able to fetch webtests but my intention is to fetch webtest operations(from azure.mgmt.applicationinsights.v2015_05_01.operations import WebTestsOperations) help on this. Clarify one thing for me, if I am able to fetch webtests from sdk it seems that this point is done -->>> Add Azure Service Management API permissions under user_impersonation in Azure Active Directory i thins so.

 Thanks in Advance

Comment: @Sampath, I could aslo see this Error   
azure.core.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundError: (InvalidResourceType) The resource type 'operations' could not be found in the namespace 'Microsoft.Insights' for api version '2015-05-01'. The supported api-versions are '2014-04-01,2014-06-01,2015-04-01'.
Code: InvalidResourceType
Message: The resource type 'operations' could not be found in the namespace 'Microsoft.Insights' for api version '2015-05-01'. The supported api-versions are '2014-04-01,2014-06-01,2015-04-01'.

Comment: @VINAYTALLA The error message ` azure.core.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundError,` indicates that you are trying to access a resource type called 'operations' in the 'Microsoft.Insights' namespace using API version '2015-05-01,' but this combination of resource type and API version is not supported. The error message also suggests that the supported API versions for this resource type are '2014-04-01,' '2014-06-01,' and '2015-04-01.' Please check with the version I am able to run my code with every version and with out `.v2015_05_01`

Comment: @VINAYTALLA will sreach for related MSDOC related fetch webtest operations(from azure.mgmt.applicationinsights.v2015_05_01.operations import WebTestsOperations) and get back to you

Comment: @VINAYTALLA refer this git for other [methods](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/main/sdk/applicationinsights/azure-mgmt-applicationinsights/generated_samples). Thank you. These are the only methods from the reference. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Sampath, is there a chance to get response body for the failed requests in Application Insights using Rest API or KQL or SDK. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Yes using the Azure function or REST API

Comment: azure function [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-python?pivots=python-mode-configuration)

Comment: rest api [reference](https://rapidapi.com/blog/how-to-use-an-api-with-python/)

Comment: Hi @Sampath,  I have attached Screen Shot above which might help. Application Insights Failed Requests

Comment: @VINAYTALLA it  `401 Unauthorized` error 400-499 response codes indicate an issue that is initiated from the client. These issues can range from the client initiating requests to an unmatched hostname, request timeout, unauthenticated request, malicious request, and more. any different code you tried

Comment: @Sampath, Now you are on the right point, here what ever the error  just I need  to fetch The  Error Response through the API or SDK so that I can automate and attach to mail body.

Answer (score 0):

- Interact with Azure Application Insights Management with web tests used to monitor the availability and performance of web applications.
- Using the `list_by_resource_group` method and iterates through the paginated results to print information about each web test.
- Add Azure Service Management API permissions under user_impersonation in Azure Active Directory.
- Register the application in Azure Active Directory with the `Contributor` role under subscription.
- Install packages `pip install azure-mgmt-applicationinsights azure-identity`.
- Create an Azure Application Insights in `Azure` and test as shown in the image below.

[image]

**Code:**

```py
from  azure.identity  import  ClientSecretCredential
from  azure.mgmt.applicationinsights.v2015_05_01  import  ApplicationInsightsManagementClient
# Replace with your Azure credentials
tenant_id = "72f988bf"
client_id = "fd6fbe8"
client_secret = "xTB8Q"
subscription_id = "b83c1ed3"
resource_group_name = "sampath"
web_test_name = "testname-ApplicationInsightsName"
# Create Azure Application Insights Management Client
credential = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id=tenant_id,  client_id=client_id,  client_secret=client_secret)
client = ApplicationInsightsManagementClient(credential=credential,  subscription_id=subscription_id)
# Retrieve a specific web test
response = client.web_tests.get(resource_group_name=resource_group_name,  web_test_name=web_test_name)
print("Web Test Response:")
print(response)
# List all web tests in a resource group
operation = client.web_tests
paged_object = operation.list_by_resource_group(resource_group_name=resource_group_name)
print("\nList of Web Tests:")
for  page  in  paged_object.by_page():
for  web_test  in  page:
print(web_test)
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Sampath, I am able to fetch webtests but my intention is to fetch webtest operations(from azure.mgmt.applicationinsights.v2015_05_01.operations import WebTestsOperations)  help on this. 

Clarify one thing for me, if I am able to fetch webtests from sdk it seems that this point is done   -->>> Add Azure Service Management API permissions under user_impersonation in Azure Active Directory  i thins so.

Thanks in Advance